# Get the index of where the element is in a vector

Tags: c++, vector

g++ (GCC) 4.7.2

I have the following vector

```
vector<Observer> observers;
```

And I will push on to the vector using this:

```
observers.push_back(ob);
```

Which I will push about 10 observers on to the vector. However, I need to remove one from the vector. However, because I don't know where in the vector the observer is. How can I get the index of where it is so that I can use the index to remove it?

I will need to get the index so I can remove it using erase

```
observers.erase(observers.begin() + index);
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: How do you know about your observer? Are you using an iterator, or what?

Comment: You could just use `remove_if` from `<algorithm>` library see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use one of the [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) algorithms (possibly [find_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/) ). It will return an iterator to the correct element if it matches your criteria, that you can directly give to `erase()`.

```
std::vector<Observer>::iterator toErase;
//Pick one of the following
toErase = std::find_if(observers.begin(), observers.end(),/*your predicate here*/);
toErase = std::find(observers.begin(), observers.end(), observerToDelete);

//If we found an observer matching the criteria
if(toErase != observers.end()){
    observers.erase(toErase);
}
```

Comment: You need `std::find_if` if you want to pass a predicate.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `std::find` but you need to overload equality `==` operator for your Observer class so that program knows how to compare your objects

Comment: You mean `operator==`. Also, an alternative could be to use `std::find_if`.

Answer (score 2):

[`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) should work for this. `std::find(observers.begin(), observers.end(), ob)`

Answer (score 0):

Is it really *that* hard?

```
int i = 0;
while (i < observers.size() && observers[i] != observerToDelete)
    i++;
// Replace the != with any other way of comparing observers
// if needed

if (i < observers.size())
    // found
```

(apart from mentioned `std::find`, iterators and 1000 more methods to do it)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use [std:map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) if you know name of observer

Answer (score -1):

You can use "std::find" for it, but maybe you don't need a "vector" at all. Maybe you should consider using "set" container instead. It is a rightful alternative when indices are not importrant.

Comment: There is nothing in the post to suggest that a set is a suitable container.

Comment: I might of misinterpreted this: "However, because I don't know where in the vector the observer is". If the objects are more likely to be idetified by value than indices, set is the best choice.

Comment: But there is nothing to say sequence has to be unique, or that a node based container is needed, or that the type has a natural ordering.

Comment: I see this as the question implies that for every observer there is one index - that's uniqueness. Well, I could be wrong, that's why I used the word "maybe" in the first place.